# Sketchup API for navigating around a model (eventually to integrate with Leap Motion)

Tags: sketchup, leap-motion

I'm trying to use to SketchUp API to navigate around 3D models (zoom, pan, rotate, etc). My ultimate aim is to integrate it with a Leap Motion app.

However, right now I think my first step would be to figure out how to control the basic navigation gestures via the Sketchup API. After a bit of research, I see that there are the 'Camera' and the 'Animation' interfaces, but I think they would be more suited to 'hardcoded' paths and motions within the script.

Therefore I was wondering - does anyone know how I can write a plugin that is able to accept inputs from another program (my eventual Leap Motion App in this case) and translate it into specific navigation commands using the Sketchup API (like pan, zoom, etc). Can this be done using the 'Camera' and the 'Animation' interfaces (in some sort of step increments), or are there other interfaces I should be looking at.

As usual, and examples would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that after Thomthom's answer, I was having problems with the view seemingly 'jumping' when I created a new camera and assigned it to the current view. I finally figured out this was due to the FOV of both cameras being different. I have posted this as an answer on this same thread.

Answer (score 1):

`View`, `Camera` and the `Animation` class is what you are looking for. Maybe you don't even need the `Animation` class, you might just be ok with using the time in the `UI` class. Depends on the details of what you will be doing.

You can set the camera directly like so:
`Sketchup.active_model.active_view.camera.set(ORIGIN, Z_AXIS, Y_AXIS)`

or you can use `View.camera=` which also accept a transition time argument if you find that useful.

For bridging input you could always create a Ruby C Extension that takes care of the communication between the applications. There are some quirks in getting C Extensions work for SketchUp Ruby as oppose to regular Ruby though - depending on how you compile it.
I wrote a hello world example a couple of years ago: https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/sketchup-ruby-c-extension

Though note that I have since found a better solution for Windows, using the Development Kit from Ruby Installers: http://rubyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to my comment above regarding the view seemingly 'jumping' when I assign a new camera to the current view using camera=, but not if I use camera.set.

I figured out this was happening because the camera FOV for the original camera was different, and the new camera was defaulting to an FOV of 30. By explicitly creating the camera with the optional perspective and FOV arguments from the initial camera solves this problem:

```
new_camera = Sketchup::Camera.new new_eye, new_target, curr_camera.up, curr_camera.perspective?, curr_camera.fov
```

Hope people find this useful!